# How to change permissions of a hdd partition to suit PLEX

Tags: plex

I'm a total newbie when it comes to linux (brought up on windows but fancied a change). I have converted a spare machine to a media server using windows 7, but it got very very slow to the point where I couldn't use it any more.
Anyway to cut a long story short, I swapped to Ubuntu (the latest stable version 13.10 I believe)  today and I'm trying to use it along side PLEX (I've read great reviews).

So far, I'm pretty sure everything is as it's meant to be. Ubuntu is running so smooth and quick in comparison to Windows 7 and I've installed PLEX.

That said, I can't seem to get PLEX to find any of the folders I want to share on my media partition. Someone suggested I change the permissions on the partition to suit PLEX, so I've right clicked on the partitioned drive icon and set the sharing options accordingly as I would have done with windows. I've noticed the permissions tab, but Ubuntu won't allow me to change the permissions for the group (which I think is what I need to do) ...please can anyone advise me further?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/395291/plex-media-server-wont-find-media-external-hard-drive

Comment: Is this still reproducible?