# How can I access a Windows NTFS drive on a plex server

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, permissions, mount, plex

I'm using Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual booting.

I've installed plex server but it cannot access my Windows volume (C,D)

I have run the commands

```
sudo chmod -R 777
gedit /etc/fstab
```

and added the volume in the fstab file

I ran `cat /proc/mounts`

and added this line in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda2 /media/virajlinux/New\040Volume fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

That didn't work, so I tried this line

```
/dev/sda2 /media/virajlinux/New\040Volume fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 2
```

I unsuccessfully tried:

- [Plex Media Manager sees external NTFS drive but doesn't see directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620363/plex-media-manager-sees-external-ntfs-drive-but-doesnt-see-directories)
- [Plex Media Server: Won't find media External Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395291/plex-media-server-wont-find-media-external-hard-drive)

I want to run plex without any effect on Windows 10.

How can I fix it?

[image: add folder dialogue]

Comment: See answer.  `fuseblk` has no place in `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, found the solution:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:plex:rx /media/{USERNAME}/
```

For this question in this specific case you need to run

```
sudo setfacl -m u:plex:rx /media/virajlinux/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a dual-boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu, Plex server installed on the Ubuntu partition. You want to *read* the Windows ntfs partions "C" and "D" but you don't want *write* access to make sure that Windows 10 runs without any issues later.

Assuming that your Windows partions are /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3, put the following lines in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2                                  /media/virajlinux/C     ntfs         defaults,umask=002         0       0
/dev/sda3                                  /media/virajlinux/D     ntfs         defaults,umask=002         0       0
```

and point Plex to them accordingly. Windows drives are mounted at boot of the Ubuntu partition with the Plex media server, and they are read-only.

This should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing `ntfs-3g` (as mentioned in the comments)

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

then edit the `fstab`file with your favorite ediotr

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

to this

```
/dev/sda2 /media/virajlinux/New\040Volume ntfs-3g    permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2
```

Disclaimer: There are *[a lot of options](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#6)*  you can pass here, but with **permissions`** you can do things like`chmod`or`chown`, which might help with`plex`.

Then, if the volume `/dev/sda2` is **not** mounted do

```
sudo mount -a
```

if you get an error similar to

```
mount: /dev/sda2 is busy
```

then do

```
sudo umount /dev/sda2 && sudo mount -a
```

Comment: `/dev/sda2 /media/virajlinux/New\040Volume ntfs-3g    defaults,umask=002,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2`is it correct

Comment: Should be fine, yes !

Comment: i'll try it but it's not working. i'll update question